# Iot Hub - default event hub receive same message twice

Tags: azure-iot-hub

I'm having APi Service that handle some information from my device. After that i use default Iot-HUB SDK that allows me to send data into Iot-Hub. In my event hub I usually get data that I send more than once. Is there any options to see what it happens ? Maybe some extra settings that to retransmission or something that send messages more than once from my web api service ?

Comment: Can you show a code sample to reproduce your issue?

Comment: Currently I find isue. The problem is that I use Mqtt as a send protocol in my web api. After change it into Http my problem is solved.

Comment: We have the exact same problem. We are using the SDK for .NET Core 2.1. At some rare occasions the same message is send multiple times (2-5 times - it is random). We are using the MQTT protocol. What is the reason for this? Can somebody elaborate on this problem? Is it a known issue and is there a fix or a workaround?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem with my code. I was sending messages to an iothub using an Azure function. I had the message sending time trigger as a variable. When sending messages in shorter frequencies (i.e. messages that are sent each second) some of these messages are duplicated. 
By changing the message protocol it solved. Given below is the corrected code,

```
DeviceClient deviceClient = DeviceClient.CreateFromConnectionString(connectionString, TransportType.Http1);
```

Comment: What is the problem with the other protocols? Is there a fix or a workaround using the MQTT protocol?